# How to use 'While Loop' in Django template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I want to restrict user login session upto some definite number,after which the same user cant access login option, i want to do it with 'while loop', the way i used to do in python

example

```
cnt = 0
while i<=5:
    print (i)
    cnt =+1
```

But how to exactly write them in 'Django Template Format'? Please be helping me out. Thank you.

Comment: You can't set a variable `{{ cnt }}` in the template and store its value between requests. If you're trying to restrict the user to 5 login attempts, then that logic belongs in the view, not the template.

Comment: everything in templates gets rendered before the user gets his HTML. You can't do the backend in frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would discourage originating this in the template. I would recommend the following:

In your login view, add a conditional that says if the user's number of logins has exceeded a certain number, render a different template, which would say that the max number of logins has been exceeded.

Please note that this will require you to record the number of logins done by a user. For this, my first guess would be to add a field to the user, and increase its value by one each time the user_logged_in signal is called.

I also wouldn't recommend storing this as a session variable, as clearing cookies would then easily bypass your system. If you do want to do it as a session variable rather than a user field, your steps would be pretty much the same:

When the user_logged_in signal is called, augment a session variable by 1. Then, provide this session variable as context to any templates that need it. Use an if block from there. Additionally, be sure to add it into your login view (always strive to have both client side and server side validation)